# How do I show If $f(B_r)$ is in a rectangle with side $Mr$ and $ \epsilon r$.

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a continuously differentiable function. Suppose that the Jacobian determinant $Df(0,0)$ is equal to zero. show that for $\epsilon >0$ there exist $M, \delta>0$ with the following property:

If $B_r$ is the closed disk of radius $r<\delta$ centered at $(0,0)$, then $f(B_r)$ is contained in a rectangle with side $Mr$ and $ \epsilon r$.

Here the $Df(0,0)$ is equal to zero, so I cannot apply the Inverse Function theorem here. Can anyone suggest me it's solution?

Answer (score 1):

WLOG $f(0,0)=(0,0)$.  Since $\det Df(0,0)=0$, we rotate both domain and codomain $\mathbb{R}^2$ independently so $Df(0,0)$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\text{ some }a\geq 0.
$$
Choose $\delta>0$ such that on $B_\delta$, $Df(x,y)$ deviates from $Df(0,0)$ by less than $\frac12\epsilon$ in every entry.  Then, for all $(x,y)\in B_r$, $r<\delta$, we have $\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert\leq\sqrt{2}r<2r$ and
\begin{align*}
\lvert f_1(x,y)-ax\rvert&
=\left\lvert\int_0^1 \left[D_{(x,y)}f_1(tx,ty)-D_{(x,y)}f_1(0,0)\right]\mathrm{d}t\right\rvert\\
&\leq\int_0^1\Big\lvert [Df_1(tx,ty)-Df_1(0,0)](x,y)\Big\rvert\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\leq\int_0^1\Big[\underbrace{\lvert\partial_1f_1(tx,ty)-a\rvert}_{\leq\frac12\epsilon}\lvert x\rvert+\lvert\underbrace{\partial_2f_1(tx,ty)\rvert}_{\leq\frac12\epsilon}\lvert y\rvert\Big]\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\leq\frac12\epsilon(\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert)< r\epsilon
\end{align*}
and similarly $\lvert f_2(x,y)\rvert<\epsilon r$.  So $M=a+\epsilon$ would do.

Comment: How do you find $Df(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix}{a~~0\\ 0~~0}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Because determinant is 0, there is an column eigenvector (on the right) for eigenvalue $0$ so choose a rotation on the domain to match that to the second coordinate.  Also there is a row eigenvector (on the left) for eigenvalue $0$ so choose a rotation of the codomain to match that.

Comment: Do you mean you choose one column vector $(a,0)^T$, then start rotating with matrix $\begin{bmatrix}{cos(\alpha)~~-sin(\alpha)\\sin(\alpha)~~cos(\alpha)}\end{bmatrix}$?